# 2D Histogram with normalized rows

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 2d, histogram

I want to draw a 2D histogram with each row normalized. I'm using the following code:

```
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(charged_zgs, zgs, weights=prescales, normed=1, range=[[0, 0.5], [0, 0.5]], bins=25)
Hmasked = np.ma.masked_where(H==0,H) # Mask pixels with a value of zero

plt.pcolormesh(xedges,yedges,Hmasked)

cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Counts')  

plt.show()
```

However, the `normed=1` bit makes the double integral 1 while I want each individual rows to be normalized.

I thought I could use a list of tuples for weights that I could normalize manually but then realized that the argument weights must be a 1D list.

Comment: Of you normalize every row, it's not a histogram anymore. It's probably easier to prepare your data in a matrix, normalize as you wish and then use `matshow` or `imshow` to draw your matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid taking all of the transposed by using `keepdims=True`:

```
H_norm_rows = H / H.max(axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to normalize each row, you can use:

```
H_norm_rows = (H.T/np.sum(H,axis=1)).T
```